# TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'authenticate'

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, passport.js, passport-local

I am integrating SailsJS and Passport. I have a fairly simply controller but during the "process" method where I process the login I get the following error:

> TypeError: Object `#<Object>` has no method 'authenticate'

You can see in the controller I am calling the passport.authenticate() method, according to docs this should exist.

LoginController.js

```
module.exports = {
  login: function(req, res) {
    res.view("login",{});
  },
  process: function(req, res) {

    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
      if( (err)||(!user) ) {
        return res.send({
          message: 'login failed'
        });
        res.send(err);
      }
      req.logIn(user, function(err) {
        if(err) res.send(err);
        return res.send({
          message: 'login successful'
        });
      });
    }) (req, res);
  },

  logout: function(req, res) {
    req.logOut();
    res.send('logout successful');
  }
};
```

Comment: Where are you requiring passport?

Comment: @idbehold well, unfortunately I wasn't.  I am a Java programmer working in NodeJS lol, I thought npm installs in SailsJS were wrapped up with grunt and included some where automatigically

Answer (score 0):

@idbehold got this one, I wasn't requiring passport any where.